# Can't print/access $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

This is my code:

```
// Save stuff to session
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
$_SESSION['name'] = $user_profile[name];

// Redirect to test page
header( 'Location: http://www.justwalk.it/test.php' ) ;
```

If I print session instead of redirecting I get it with no problems:

```
Array ( [uid] => xx [rank] => xx  [name] => xx )
```

However when redirecting in test.php I already can't print the session. The only code in test.php it is:

```
<? session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);?>
```

But it prints `array()` and `$_SESSION['uid']` doesn't return anything at all.

I don't believe the session has been unset as it sometimes pops out in other places on my page. It's simply not accessible all the time. And I don't know why. What am I doing wrong? Or if I'm not doing anything wrong what could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: might be a silly question, but did you remember to session_start() before saving values to $_SESSION?

Comment: Is `justwalk.it` the domain you currently are on?

Comment: Make sure you call `session_start();` on **every** page before you use the `$_SESSION` superglobal, whether you are assigning *or* reading values.

Comment: yes, I checked just in case but I did. There is session_start(), I write to it, I redirect and I try to print it again.

Comment: I have it on all pages, I'm now testing just 2 pages: login.php and test.php both have session_start(); as first line, I narrowed the possibilities to almost none and still I can't access session. However it randomly works on the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no code unsetting the session, it might be worth checking if you are accessing the original script using the non-www version of your URL and then redirecting to the www one.

Another cause could, as T1000 mentioned, be output being sent before `session_start()`, UTF8 BOM character is notorious for causing sometimes invisible output.

Comment: It was just that. I was just coming to answer my own question, the first file didn't have www. and I was redirecting to www. I had no idea this happened, thankfully I discovered before throwing my laptop through the window

Comment: It's always the small things :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you send HTML or something to the browser before session_start() ...
You can also set error_reporting to E_ALL and check the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

In test.php, check that session_start() isn't returning FALSE, indicating a failure to create or resume a session:

```
if (! session_start()) die "OMG, total session asplosion.";
```

If that's the problem, you'll probably have to go through your error logs to figure out what's up.  (Actually, anything in your error logs?)